# Python 2 dynamic multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 3 I can use list expansion to dynamically inherit from multiple superclasses:

```
class Super1(object):
    x = 1

class Super2(object):
    y = 1

classes = [Super1, Super2]

class B(*classes):
    pass
```

This lets me allow for runtime decisions about which mixin classes to add to the list of superclasses.

Unfortunately, the `*` expansion of the superclass list is a syntax error in python2. Is there a generally accepted way of choosing the list of superclasses at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metaclass to populate `B`'s base classes instead:

```
classes = Super1, Super2

class B:
    __metaclass__ = lambda name, _, attrs: type(name, classes, attrs)

print(B.__bases__)
```

This outputs:

```
(<class '__main__.Super1'>, <class '__main__.Super2'>)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @blhsing is correct, but I actually wanted something that was 2/3 compatible. I took the cue of using `type` directly and did something more like this:

```
class Super1(object):
    x = 1

class Super2(object):
    y = 1

classes = [Super1, Super2]

B = type('B', tuple(classes), {})
```

Which works equally well in 2/3